# Combinations of integers

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I still try to get intuitive feeling of permutations and combinations, so far without much success. I am confused by the following exercise.

**Exercise.** Four integers are chosen at random between 0 and 9, inclusive. Find the probability that (a) they are all different, (b) not more than 2 are the same.

**Answers** a) $\frac{63}{125}$ b) $\frac{963}{1000}$

**Ideas:**

a) $\frac{9}{10}\frac{8}{10}\frac{7}{10}=\frac{63}{125}$. Good!

b)P (no more than 2 are the same) = 1 - P(all 4 are the same) - P(any 3 are the same)

P(all 4 are the same) = $\frac{1}{1000}$

P(any 3 are the same) = ?. Here the problem. I assume I should appreciate the probability by counting. Let try to do so

$_{4}P_{10}$ - total number of permutations.

$10$ - variations of the same numbers.

I am hot sure whether it's a right reasoning, if you know how to solve this exercise please share it with us.

Comment: Note that in calculating "not more than 2 are the same", you missed out cases of the form $A, A, B, B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’d do the second problem by counting rather than by working directly with probabilities. There are $10^4$ sequences altogether. The ‘bad’ sequences are those in which all $4$ numbers are the same; those with $3$ identical numbers and $1$ different number; and those with two pairs of identical numbers.

- There are $10$ sequences in which all $4$ numbers are the same.
- There are $10\cdot9=90$ ways to choose a number for the triplet and a different number for the unmatched one. There are then $4$ possible positions in the sequence for the unmatched number, so there are $4\cdot90=360$ sequences of this type.
- For the two pairs case there are $10$ ways to choose the number that appears first in the sequence, and $9$ ways to choose the other number. There are $3$ possible positions for the mate to the first number, so there are $10\cdot9\cdot3=270$ sequences of this type.

Altogether we have $10+360+270=640$ ‘bad’ sequences, leaving $10000-640=9360$ ‘good’ sequences. The probability of getting a ‘good’ sequence is therefore $$\frac{9360}{10000}=0.936=\frac{117}{125}\;.$$

It’s actually easier to count the ‘good’ sequences directly. There are $4!\binom{10}4=5040$ sequences with no repeated numbers. A sequence with exactly $2$ identical numbers must contain $3$ distinct numbers, one of them repeated. There are $\binom{10}3=120$ ways to choose the $3$ numbers, there are then $3$ ways to choose which one is to be repeated, there are $\binom42=6$ ways to pick $2$ positions in the sequence for the matched pair, and there are then $2$ ways to distribute the other two numbers to the remaining $2$ positions. Thus, there are $120\cdot3\cdot6\cdot2=4320$ sequences with exactly $2$ identical numbers, and a total of $5040+4320=9360$ ‘good’ sequences. The probability of getting one of them is therefore $\frac{9360}{10000}$, exactly as before.